# Would selenium act as a p-type dopant for gallium?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I have been learning about the doping of semiconductors lately and haven't been able to see if this specific pair would work. I saw a paper in which tellerium was used as a P-type dopant for thallium, and since thallium has the same number of valence electrons as gallium, and selenium has the same number of valence electrons as tellerium, I am guessing that this might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gallium is a metal, not a semiconductor, so the effect of doping it should be negligible compared to the metal's conductivity, if I am not mistaken On the other hand, the compound GaSe is a semiconductor.

EDIT (02/02/2018): By the way, thallium is also a metal, so it is strange that it is doped by tellurium. A reference could be helpful.